# How to count with when xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

In my xslt i am outputting customers who have sim cards involved with country code 49, area code 31, number 124567. In the When i am outputting any customer who has confirmed identity = 0 which were involved with these numbers. I need another when which outputs customers who have more than one sim card also involved with the numbers country code 49, area code 31, number 124567. The customers who have more than one sim card have customerID repeated more than once inside the sims/sim node. I am not sure how to calculate this in another when under the confirmed identity when.

XSLT CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="customerid" match="database/sims/sim" use="customerID" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Customers</title>
</head>
<body>
<table rules="all">
<caption>Customers</caption>
<thead>
<tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Surname</th></tr>
</thead>

<xsl:for-each select="database/calls/call">

<xsl:if test="countryCodeOfOtherParty  = '49' and areaCodeOfOtherParty ='31' and numberCodeOfOtherParty ='124567'">

<xsl:variable name="callsimID" select="./simID"/> 

<xsl:for-each select= "/database/sims/sim[simID = $callsimID]">

<xsl:variable name="simCustomerID" select="./customerID"/> 

<xsl:for-each select= "/database/customers/customer[customerID = $simCustomerID]">

<tr>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="confirmedIdentity=0">
<td bgcolor="#FFA500"><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></td> 
<td bgcolor="#FFA500"><xsl:value-of select="surname"/></td> 
</xsl:when>

</xsl:choose>
</tr>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML CODE:

```
<database>
<towers>
<tower>
<towerID>1</towerID>
<degreesNorth>51</degreesNorth>
<minutesNorth>57</minutesNorth>
<secondsNorth>0</secondsNorth>
<degreesWest>8</degreesWest>
<minutesWest>30</minutesWest>
<secondsWest>0</secondsWest>
<streetAddress>1 Low Road</streetAddress>
<townName>Blahtown</townName>
<countyName>Cork</countyName>
</tower>
<tower>
<towerID>2</towerID>
<degreesNorth>52</degreesNorth>
<minutesNorth>50</minutesNorth>
<secondsNorth>1</secondsNorth>
<degreesWest>8</degreesWest>
<minutesWest>54</minutesWest>
<secondsWest>0</secondsWest>
<streetAddress>1 High Avenue</streetAddress>
<townName>Blahville</townName>
<countyName>Cork</countyName>
</tower>
<tower>
<towerID>3</towerID>
<degreesNorth>51</degreesNorth>
<minutesNorth>30</minutesNorth>
<secondsNorth>2</secondsNorth>
<degreesWest>8</degreesWest>
<minutesWest>17</minutesWest>
<secondsWest>2</secondsWest>
<streetAddress>1 Main Street</streetAddress>
<townName>Blahley</townName>
<countyName>Cork</countyName>
</tower>
<tower>
<towerID>4</towerID>
<degreesNorth>51</degreesNorth>
<minutesNorth>16</minutesNorth>
<secondsNorth>3</secondsNorth>
<degreesWest>9</degreesWest>
<minutesWest>30</minutesWest>
<secondsWest>45</secondsWest>
<streetAddress>1 East Street</streetAddress>
<townName>Blahborough</townName>
<countyName>Cork</countyName>
</tower>
</towers>
<customers>
<customer>
<customerID>1</customerID>
<surname>Aardvark</surname>
<firstname>John</firstname>
<streetAddress>101 High Street</streetAddress>
<townName>Dorptown</townName>
<countyName>Wicklow</countyName>
<contractOrPrepaid>contract</contractOrPrepaid>
<confirmedIdentity>1</confirmedIdentity>
</customer>
<customer>
<customerID>2</customerID>
<surname>Brown</surname>
<firstname>James</firstname>
<streetAddress>102 High Street</streetAddress>
<townName>Dorptown</townName>
<countyName>Wicklow</countyName>
<contractOrPrepaid>prepaid</contractOrPrepaid>
<confirmedIdentity>0</confirmedIdentity>
</customer>
<customer>
<customerID>3</customerID>
<surname>Brown</surname>
<firstname>Jack</firstname>
<streetAddress>103 Main Street</streetAddress>
<townName>Dorpville</townName>
<countyName>Cork</countyName>
<contractOrPrepaid>prepaid</contractOrPrepaid>
<confirmedIdentity>1</confirmedIdentity>
</customer>
<customer>
<customerID>4</customerID>
<surname>Carroll</surname>
<firstname>Jack</firstname>
<streetAddress>103 Main Street</streetAddress>
<townName>Dorpton</townName>
<countyName>Kilkenny</countyName>
<contractOrPrepaid>prepaid</contractOrPrepaid>
<confirmedIdentity>0</confirmedIdentity>
</customer>
<customer>
<customerID>5</customerID>
<surname>Brown</surname>
<firstname>Peter</firstname>
<streetAddress>103 Main Street</streetAddress>
<townName>Dorpborough</townName>
<countyName>Kilkenny</countyName>
<contractOrPrepaid>contract</contractOrPrepaid>
<confirmedIdentity>1</confirmedIdentity>
</customer>
<customer>
<customerID>6</customerID>
<surname>Brown</surname>
<firstname>Xavier</firstname>
<streetAddress>103 Main Street</streetAddress>
<townName>Dorpley</townName>
<countyName>Kilkenny</countyName>
<contractOrPrepaid>contract</contractOrPrepaid>
<confirmedIdentity>1</confirmedIdentity>
</customer>
<customer>
<customerID>7</customerID>
<surname>Brown</surname>
<firstname>Xavier</firstname>
<streetAddress>103 Main Street</streetAddress>
<townName>Dorpton Bridge</townName>
<countyName>Wexford</countyName>
<contractOrPrepaid>prepaid</contractOrPrepaid>
<confirmedIdentity>0</confirmedIdentity>
</customer>
<customer>
<customerID>8</customerID>
<surname>Brown</surname>
<firstname>Xavier</firstname>
<streetAddress>103 High Street</streetAddress>
<townName>New Dorpley</townName>
<countyName>Carlow</countyName>
<contractOrPrepaid>prepaid</contractOrPrepaid>
<confirmedIdentity>0</confirmedIdentity>
</customer>
</customers>
<sims>
<sim>
<simID>1</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234567</number>
<customerID>1</customerID>
<yearPurchased>1995</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>2</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234568</number>
<customerID>2</customerID>
<yearPurchased>1995</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>11</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>11</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>3</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234569</number>
<customerID>3</customerID>
<yearPurchased>1996</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>4</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234570</number>
<customerID>4</customerID>
<yearPurchased>1997</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>5</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234571</number>
<customerID>5</customerID>
<yearPurchased>1998</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>6</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234572</number>
<customerID>6</customerID>
<yearPurchased>1999</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>7</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234573</number>
<customerID>7</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2000</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>8</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234574</number>
<customerID>8</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2001</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>9</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234575</number>
<customerID>1</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2001</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>10</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234576</number>
<customerID>2</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2002</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>11</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234577</number>
<customerID>3</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2003</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>12</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234578</number>
<customerID>4</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2004</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>13</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234579</number>
<customerID>4</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2005</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>14</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234580</number>
<customerID>5</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2006</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>15</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234581</number>
<customerID>5</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2007</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
<sim>
<simID>16</simID>
<areaCode>081</areaCode>
<number>1234582</number>
<customerID>5</customerID>
<yearPurchased>2008</yearPurchased>
<monthPurchased>10</monthPurchased>
<dayPurchsed>12</dayPurchsed>
</sim>
</sims>
<calls>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567890</callID>
<simID>1</simID>
<madeOrReceived>received</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>12</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567891</callID>
<simID>2</simID>
<madeOrReceived>made</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>13</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567892</callID>
<simID>3</simID>
<madeOrReceived>made</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>14</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567893</callID>
<simID>4</simID>
<madeOrReceived>received</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>15</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567894</callID>
<simID>5</simID>
<madeOrReceived>received</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>16</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567895</callID>
<simID>6</simID>
<madeOrReceived>received</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>17</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567896</callID>
<simID>7</simID>
<madeOrReceived>made</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>18</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567897</callID>
<simID>8</simID>
<madeOrReceived>made</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>19</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567898</callID>
<simID>9</simID>
<madeOrReceived>made</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>20</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567899</callID>
<simID>10</simID>
<madeOrReceived>made</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>44</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>123</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>21</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567900</callID>
<simID>11</simID>
<madeOrReceived>received</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>353</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>021</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>22</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567901</callID>
<simID>12</simID>
<madeOrReceived>made</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>353</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>056</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>7654321</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>23</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567902</callID>
<simID>2</simID>
<madeOrReceived>received</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>49</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>31</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>124567</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>24</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567903</callID>
<simID>14</simID>
<madeOrReceived>received</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>49</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>31</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>124567</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>25</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567904</callID>
<simID>6</simID>
<madeOrReceived>made</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>49</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>31</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>124567</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>26</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
<call>
<callID>12345678901234567905</callID>
<simID>7</simID>
<madeOrReceived>received</madeOrReceived>
<countryCodeOfOtherParty>49</countryCodeOfOtherParty>
<areaCodeOfOtherParty>31</areaCodeOfOtherParty>
<numberCodeOfOtherParty>124567</numberCodeOfOtherParty>
<year>2009</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>27</day>
<hour>12</hour>
<minute>12</minute>
<second>5</second>
</call>
</calls>
<towerUsages>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567890</callID>
<towerID>1</towerID>
<durationOfUse>180</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567891</callID>
<towerID>2</towerID>
<durationOfUse>125</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567891</callID>
<towerID>3</towerID>
<durationOfUse>90</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567891</callID>
<towerID>1</towerID>
<durationOfUse>36</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567892</callID>
<towerID>2</towerID>
<durationOfUse>145</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567893</callID>
<towerID>1</towerID>
<durationOfUse>56</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567893</callID>
<towerID>4</towerID>
<durationOfUse>67</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567894</callID>
<towerID>3</towerID>
<durationOfUse>135</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567895</callID>
<towerID>3</towerID>
<durationOfUse>78</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567895</callID>
<towerID>1</towerID>
<durationOfUse>35</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567896</callID>
<towerID>3</towerID>
<durationOfUse>138</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567897</callID>
<towerID>4</towerID>
<durationOfUse>30</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567897</callID>
<towerID>3</towerID>
<durationOfUse>137</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567898</callID>
<towerID>4</towerID>
<durationOfUse>140</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567899</callID>
<towerID>2</towerID>
<durationOfUse>70</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567899</callID>
<towerID>3</towerID>
<durationOfUse>85</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567899</callID>
<towerID>1</towerID>
<durationOfUse>67</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567900</callID>
<towerID>2</towerID>
<durationOfUse>148</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567901</callID>
<towerID>3</towerID>
<durationOfUse>95</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567902</callID>
<towerID>1</towerID>
<durationOfUse>146</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567903</callID>
<towerID>1</towerID>
<durationOfUse>85</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567904</callID>
<towerID>15</towerID>
<durationOfUse>125</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
<towerUsage>
<callID>12345678901234567905</callID>
<towerID>4</towerID>
<durationOfUse>120</durationOfUse>
</towerUsage>
</towerUsages>
</database>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need "when"s here. You can use predicates to filter nodes. I hope this works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="customerid" match="database/sims/sim" use="customerID" />
<xsl:key name="sim" match="database/sims/sim" use="simID"/>
<xsl:key name="simByCustID" match="database/sims/sim" use="customerID"/>
<xsl:key name="customer" match="database/customers/customer" use="customerID"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Customers</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table rules="all">
                <caption>Customers</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Firstname</th>
                        <th>Surname</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <xsl:for-each select="database/calls/call[countryCodeOfOtherParty  = '49' and areaCodeOfOtherParty ='31' and numberCodeOfOtherParty ='124567']">
                    <xsl:variable name="callsimID" select="simID"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select= "key('sim', $callsimID)">
                        <xsl:variable name="simCustomerID" select="customerID"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select= "key('customer', $simCustomerID)[count(key('simByCustID', $simCustomerID)) > 1][confirmedIdentity=0]">
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#FFA500">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
                                </td>
                                <td bgcolor="#FFA500">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="surname"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks but i wish to output customers with more than 1 sim card in one colour and customers who have confirmed identity equal to 0 in another colour. I think i would need a when for this.